# Adding a live chat to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

I'm using a plugin for a *share and contact* sidebar.

The button bar looks like:

```
var defaults = { 
  effect  : '', // slide-on-scroll
  buttons : {
      'facebook':   { class: 'facebook',  use: false, icon: 'facebook',    link: '', title: 'Follow on Facebook' },
      'google':     { class: 'gplus',     use: false, icon: 'google-plus', link: '', title: 'Visit on Google Plus' },
      'linkedin':   { class: 'linkedin',  use: false, icon: 'linkedin',    link: '', title: 'Visit on LinkedIn' },
      'twitter':    { class: 'twitter',   use: false, icon: 'twitter',     link: '', title: 'Follow on Twitter' },
      'chat':       { class: 'livechat',  use: false, icon: 'comments', title: 'Chat with us' },
      'pinterest':  { class: 'pinterest', use: false, icon: 'pinterest',   link: '', title: 'Follow on Pinterest' },
      'phone':      { class: 'phone',     use: false, icon: 'phone',       link: '', title: 'Call us', type: 'phone' },
      'email':      { class: 'email',     use: false, icon: 'envelope',    link: '', title: 'Send us an email', type: 'email' }
  }
};
```

And calling  :

```
$.contactButtons({
  effect  : 'slide-on-scroll',
  buttons : {
    'facebook':   { class: 'facebook', use: true, link: '', extras: 'target="_blank"' },
    'linkedin':   { class: 'linkedin', use: true, link: '' },
    'google':     { class: 'gplus',    use: true, link: '' },
    'twitter':    { class: 'twitter', use: true, link: '' },
    'chat':       {class:  'livechat separated', use:true, },
    'email':      { class: 'email',    use: true, link: '' }
  }
});
```

On the chat button I want do embed a livechat app. I currently have one from https://mylivechat.com/, but I don't know how to add it to the button.

I want to hide/show the chat window when the button is clicked. I'm happy with the normal position of the chat window.

Comment: * [...] a plugin for a share and contact sidebar* Fine. And what is it called? where can we find it?

Comment: Its a script , so prity much i want wen i push the chat button to add a <script> </script> to the bottom of the body

Comment: Do you need help performing actions on button click or do you need help with adding `<script>` elements to DOM?

Comment: `its a script` Are you trolling?

Comment: Ok ....  Im using a live chat app from https://mylivechat.com/ . They give you a script that you add to the bottom of the body , you get a chat window on your page .

Comment: I want the chat window to apear and disappear wen i click that chat button from the buttons object that i linked up